# C++ vector instance variable

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm relatively new to C++ and I've run into an issue I haven't been able to resolve. The exact error I'm getting is:

> First-chance exception at 0x760d34c5 in Pg1_raycast_nabrown3.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0e296575. Unhandled
>   exception at 0x760d34c5 in Pg1_raycast_nabrown3.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x0e296575.

These are being produced when I try to access a vector instance variable. Here is the code:

**group.h**

```
class Group {

private:
    string name;
    vector<Face*> members;
    Material* material;

public:
    Group(string n);
    ~Group();

    void addFace(Face* f);
    string getName();
    vector<Face*> getMembers();
    void setMaterial(Material * mat);
    Material* getMaterial();
};
```

**group.cpp**

```
// Constructor
Group::Group(string n) {
    name = n;
}

// Deconstructor
Group::~Group() {}

/**
*   addFace
*
*   adds the provided face to this group
*/
void Group::addFace(Face* f) {

    // DEBUGGING
    OutputDebugStringA("A\n");
    OutputDebugStringA("A " + members.size());
    members.resize(members.size() + 1);
    OutputDebugStringA("B\n");
    OutputDebugStringA("B " + members.size());

    members.push_back(f);
}
```

The debug statements only print out a single "A", so its crashing on the first members.size() call. The addFace() function is being called from another class but I don't think that should be relevant code. Nothing else has interacted with the members vector.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Obviously my attempts at debug statements were causing more issues. I want to note that even removing the debug statements you've pointed out as erroneous I still receive the original error.

```
void Group::addFace(Face* f) {

    // DEBUGGING
    OutputDebugStringA("A\n");

    members.push_back(f);

    // DEBUGGING
    OutputDebugStringA("B\n");
}
```

Comment: `resize()` adds new default constructed objects to the vector if it needs to grow. You probably want `reserve()` instead.

Comment: could the problem be related to `OutputDebugString`? The result of `members.size()` is not a `string` or a string literal, but rather an integer value, so `"A " + members.size()` might result in strange behavior. Prefer something like `"A " + std::to_string(members.size())`

Comment: You don't need to use the members.resize, push_back already will reallocate the vector if necessary.

Comment: `push_back` will grow the vector as needed, so pretty much all of the code in `addFace` does not appear to be needed.

Comment: You define a destructor but no copy constructor or assignment operator.  This is an error; follow the rule of three: if you need one of them, you need them all.  (It's unclear who owns the pointers in the vector and `materials`. If something else owns them then you don't need the destructor. If this class owns them then you need a destructor, a copy ctor, and an assignment operator.)

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Will do! Though the issue is occurring prior to that resize call.

Comment: String literal + int then interpreted as a char *. Ouch.

Comment: @YoungJohn: The error occurred at the push_back() call prior to me adding the debug statements so I don't think they're responsible.

Comment: Try running in debugger and see what backtrace you get. My guess is that you are calling addFace on invalid Group pointer, but we cannot catch that from the code you posted

Answer (score 5):

You cannot concatenate strings like that in c++. `"A " + members.size()` is invalid pointer arithmetics.

You should create `std::string` from `"A "` and convert `members.size()` to `std::string`, so this line should look like:

```
OutputDebugString((std::string("A ") + std::to_string(members.size())).c_str());
```

You will need to `#include <string>` for that to work.

Comment: `OutputDebugString` won't accept a `std::string` as an argument, although your other points are correct. The correct use would be `OutputDebugString((std::string("A ") + std::to_string(members.size())).c_str());`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to use to_string because it always results in "Error: more than once instance of overloaded function".